# Training of an Autoencoder

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

Suppose I have an Autoencoder which outputs a sequence of arrays. Is it possible to run that array through a CNN and depending on the output of the CNN(Only two outputs-Yes or No), the autoencoder trains itself. For example, if the CNN says No then the Autoencoder adjusts its parameters and produces another output. This keeps happening till the CNN outputs a Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this:

```
while True:
  autoencoder.fit(input, labels)
  ae_output = autoencoder(input)
  cnn_output = CNN(ae_output).numpy()
  if cnn_output:
    break
```

Comment: Are we basically saying that the CNN is the stopping criterion for training?

Comment: @MYousefi CNN is just a function. Any function can be a criteria for anything

Comment: True. I kept reading the question and thinking that the OP wants the CNN Yes/No answer to somehow produce gradients for the AE.

Comment: @MYousefi you can add this code within `call()` method (or within Functional API) and CNN will produce gradients

Comment: I am kinda new to this whole thing. My main aim is to train the autoencoder using the value it gets from the CNN.